# Unity Google Play Game Services sign-in stop working when application goes inactive

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-signin

In my Unity app I use GPGS plugin to sign-in a user with his/her Google account on Android device. I've configured theplay game and developer accounts and the plugin as described in the [Play Game Services with Unity](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/playservices_unity) example.
The sign-in and sign-out work perfectly many times until the app goes inactive for some time. After that the app stops showing the consent dialog and I have to restart the app to make it work again.

Unity console debug output:

*[Play Games Plugin DLL] 10/16/17 13:25:25 +03:00 DEBUG: Starting Auth Transition. Op: SIGN_IN status: 10

[Play Games Plugin DLL] 10/16/17 13:25:25 +03:00 DEBUG: AuthState == Unauthenticated calling auth callbacks with failure*

Here's is the sign-in service code

```
    public class PlayGamesSignInService {

    public void init(bool signIn, Action<bool> signInCallback, bool requestEmail = false, bool requestToken = true, bool requestServerAuthCode = false) {
        const string methodName = "init";

        // Enable debugging output (recommended)
        PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;

        logDebug(methodName, "Create client configuration");
        var builder = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder();
        if (requestEmail) {
            builder.RequestEmail();
        }
        if (requestToken) {
            builder.RequestIdToken();
        }
        if (requestServerAuthCode) {
            builder.RequestServerAuthCode(false);
        }
        PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = builder.Build();

        logDebug(methodName, "Initialize and activate the platform");
        PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();

        if (signIn) {
            logDebug(methodName, "Try silent sign-in");
            PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate(signInCallback, true);
        }
    }

    public SignInResult signIn(Action<bool> signInCallback) {
        const string methodName = "signIn";

        if (!isSignedIn()) {
            try {
                logDebug(methodName, "Sign in with Play Game Services, showing the consent dialog");

                PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate(signInCallback, false);

                return SignInResult.Ok;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                logError(methodName, "Sign-in error", e);

                return SignInResult.Error;
            }
        }
        else {
            logDebug(methodName, "Already signed in");

            return SignInResult.InvalidState;
        }
    }

    public SignInResult signOut() {
        const string methodName = "signIn";

        if (isSignedIn()) {
            try {
                logDebug(methodName, "Sign out of play games");

                PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.SignOut();

                return SignInResult.Ok;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                logError(methodName, "Sign-out error", e);

                return SignInResult.Error;
            }
        }
        else {
            logDebug(methodName, "Not signed in");

            return SignInResult.InvalidState;
        }
    }

    public bool isSignedIn() {
        return PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.localUser.authenticated;
    }

    private readonly PlayGamesUser player = new PlayGamesUser();

    public PlayGamesUser getSignedInPlayer() {
        const string methodName = "updatePlayerInfo";

        if (!isSignedIn()) {
            player.id = null;

            logDebug(methodName, "Not signed in");

            return null;
        }

        PlayGamesPlatform platform = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance;
        player.id = platform.GetUserId();
        player.displayName = platform.GetUserDisplayName();
        player.email = platform.GetUserEmail();
        player.imageUrl = platform.GetUserImageUrl();
        player.googleIdToken = platform.GetIdToken();
        player.serverAuthCode = platform.GetServerAuthCode();

        return player;
    }

    private const string serviceName = "GoogleSignInService";

    private void logDebug(string methodName, string message) {
        Debug.Log(string.Format("{0}.{1}: {2}", serviceName, methodName, message));
    }

    private void logError(string methodName, string message) {
        Debug.LogError(string.Format("{0}.{1}: {2}", serviceName, methodName, message));
    }

    private void logError(string methodName, string message, Exception e) {
        if (e == null) {
            logError(methodName, message);
        }
        else {
            Debug.LogError(string.Format("GoogleSignInService.{0}: {1} {2}", methodName, message, e));
        }
    }
}

public class PlayGamesUser {
    public String id;
    public String displayName;
    public String email;
    public String imageUrl;
    public String googleIdToken;
    public String serverAuthCode;

    public override string ToString() {
        return string.Format("id: {0}, displayName: {1}, email: {2}, image: {3}, token={4}, sAuthCode={5};",
            id, displayName, email, imageUrl, googleIdToken, serverAuthCode);
    }
}

public enum SignInResult {
    Ok, InvalidState, Error
}
```

This is a code to test sign-in service

```
void Start() {
    // Get object instances
    signInButtonText = GameObject.Find("signInButton").GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
    authStatus = GameObject.Find("authStatus").GetComponent<Text>();

    GameObject startButton = GameObject.Find("startButton");
    EventSystem.current.firstSelectedGameObject = startButton;

    signInService = new PlayGamesSignInService();
    signInService.init(true, SignInCallback, requestEmail: true, requestToken: true, requestServerAuthCode: false);
}

public void SignIn() {
    if (!signInService.isSignedIn()) {
        signInService.signIn(SignInCallback);
    }
    else {
        signInService.signOut();
        signInButtonText.text = "Sign In";
        authStatus.text = "";
    }
}

public void SignInCallback(bool success) {
    if (success) {
        PlayGamesUser player = signInService.getSignedInPlayer();

        signInButtonText.text = "Sign out";
        authStatus.text = "Signed in as: " + player.displayName;

        Debug.Log("(Lollygagger) Signed in: " + player);
    }
    else {
        Debug.Log("(Lollygagger) Sign-in failed...");

        signInButtonText.text = "Sign in";
        authStatus.text = "Sign-in failed";
    }
}
```

Any suggestions, please ?

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that since this is happening after the app has been inactive for some time it may have something to do with the sign in token expiring.

You could try reauthenticating using the [MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationFocus()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationFocus.html) function. It will get called when the application is in focus again and can attempt sign in.

Example:

```
  void OnApplicationFocus(bool hasFocus)
    {
        if(hasFocus)
          //authenticate player if the sign in is no longer valid. 

    }
```

Comment: Hi Michelle, GoogleIdToken has expiration time 1 hour if you mean that. The sign-in stops working when the app is inactive for 3-5 minutes.

Comment: Ah okay, you didn't specify the time so it was the first thing that popped into my head! :)

Answer (score 0):

I did some additional study and found out that the problem occurs only in debug mode. After disabling ***USB debug*** on my mobile device and turning off all debug options in the Unity ***Build settings***, the sign-in works fine even after 1 hour sleep. Of course this is not very convinient, but at least the app works in production mode.